# Org-Mode Link Export issues (it doesn't)

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-roam

I'm having some trouble getting my org-link export to work.
Either this doesn't translate to Org-Roam-UI or I'm doing something wrong. I hope it's the latter. Mainly because I don't yet understand how the export settings work.

```lisp
(org-link-set-parameters
 "obsidian"
 :follow
 (lambda (path)
   (cl-destructuring-bind
       (vault file) (split-string path ":")
     (browse-url (format "obsidian://open?vault=%s&file=%s" vault file))))
 :export
 (lambda (path vault file description backend)
   (format (pcase backend
             ('html "<a href=\"obsidian://open?=vault%s&file=%s\">%s</a>")))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have time to explain, but try something like this and see if you have better luck. BTW, adding an example of an `obsidian` link to your question would clarify it  *a lot*.

```el
  (org-link-set-parameters
   "obsidian"
   :follow
   (lambda (path arg)
     (cl-destructuring-bind
         (vault file) (split-string path ":")
       (browse-url (format "obsidian://open?vault=%s&file=%s" vault file))))
   :export
   (lambda (path description backend info)
     (cl-destructuring-bind
         (vault file) (split-string path ":")
       (format (pcase backend
                 ('html "<a href=\"obsidian://open?vault=%s&file=%s\">%s</a>"))
             vault file description))))
```

I can't pretend that this is correct (for one, it is completely untested), but it conforms to the function signatures described in the doc string of `org-link-parameters` (which in turn is mentioned in the doc string of the function `org-link-set-parameters`). That should be your first stop in trying to understand the above.

All I can say is if you have a link in your Org mode file like this:

```org
This is my  [[obsidian:some_vault:some_file][obsidian link]].
```

then the exported HTML file contains this:

```html
This is my  <a href="obsidian://open?vault=some_vault&file=some_file">obsidian link</a>.
```

Comment: Thank you @NickD! It does make sense to me. It works in HTML export. It doesn't export to Roam-UI though. Which makes me think that there's some other backend that I haven't found yet.

Comment: I don't know anything about Roam-UI or what it means to export to it. The above specifically limits itself to `HTML` export: it's only when the backend is `html` that it produces something. Maybe you can ask a new question specifically about Roam-UI (and be sure to include some links so that people can find information about it).